# Revolution in Libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Hey am new to game development and trying to make a game using Libgdx. I want image to do revolution around a point, but when am trying its just rotating on a paraticular point. 
i don't know what am doing wrong here.

```
SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
Texture texture;
    // Font font;
    float angle = 0;
    float scale = 1;
    float vScale = 1;

@Override
public void render () {
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    spriteBatch.begin();
    spriteBatch.draw(texture, 200, 200, 46, 46, 72, 72, 4,4, angle, 0, 0, texture.getWidth(), texture.getHeight(), false, false);


    spriteBatch.end();
    angle += 20 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    scale += vScale * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    if (scale > 2) {
    vScale = -vScale;
    scale = 2;
    }
    if (scale < 0) {
    vScale = -vScale;
    scale = 0;
    }

    }
@Override
public void create () {
    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();
    texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("ui/button.png"));
    }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.